# Global convert to uppercase and lowercase in macOS?

Tags: macos, shortcut, text

In Mail.app and Text.app there's Edit > Transformations:

- Make Upper Case
- Make Lower Case
- Capitalize

...but I see no keyboard shortcut options in:
System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts:: Services.

Is there a way to get this functionality available globally for all text entry? For example, web based forums like Stack Exchange.

Of note, the options are available in Safari.app's Edit > Transformations menu:

[image: Safari screenshot]

...but not in Chrome.app:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

I could change my browser habits, but it would be nice to know if there is a way to add this functionality to all "Edit" menus.

Comment: If you are using Alfred, check this workflow out: https://github.com/alaneuler/alfred-text-manipulation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it in Safari, but Chrome ignores the standard Mac Toolbox, unfortunately.

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

You can set key commands for All Applications, which will then work for all that have the requisite menu option.

This is my own setup, which shows keys already set for Capitalise & Lower Case
I use it a lot for such as Stack Exchange.

[image]

Comment: sweet! I guess the follow up is how to override an app ignoring the standard macOS toolbox?

Comment: Don't think it can be done. There's no handle to grab, functionality just isn't in the app at all. You'd have to juggle with something that could lift it to the clipboard, edit & put it back. It's the kind of thing that maybe QuicKeys could do, but idk if it still works in recent OS X, I haven't used it since it stopped active development, several years ago.

Answer (score 3):

This free app has worked on all Mac versions for over a decade and is still current for Catalina 10.15:

#### [WordService](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wordservice/id899972312?mt=12)

> WordService provides a large number of commands for working with selected text. Extend your favorite word processor, email app, or web browser e.g. with functions for reformatting text paragraphs, cleaning up tabs, quotes, or line endings. Remove unwanted text parts, sort lines or paragraphs, change case, and do much, much more with text.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wordservice/id899972312?mt=12
- https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware

Answer (score 2):

You can install a macOS service called "Wordservice" that works great on paper, howeverI have found it to be buggy, working / not working, requiring resetting, and generally not being reliable.

But when it works it's great, and system wide.
Still trying to find a better alternative though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with Alfred by setting up a Workflow to go from the clipboard content -> lowercase -> and then paste. [This](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/workflows/utilities/transform/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20Transform%20Utility,-You%20could%20use&text=The%20Transform%20object%20will%20lowercase,will%20pass%20through%20input%20text.) article describes the setup in more detail.